# C++ Is the copy constructor called here?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Suppose you have a functions like this:

```
Foo foo() {
  Foo foo;

  // more lines of code

  return foo; // is the copy constructor called here?
}

Foo bar() {
  // more lines of code

  return Foo(); // is the copy constructor called here?
}

int main() {
  Foo a = foo();
  Foo b = bar();  
}
```

When any of the functions return, is the copy constructor called (suppose there would be one)?

Comment: What do you mean by "suppose there would be one"?  Every class has a copy constructor (though it may be `private`, or in C++0x `delete`d).  If the class doesn't declare one, it gets an implicitly-declared copy constructor.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665825/copy-constructor-vs-return-value-optimization

Comment: It's easy to test something like this.  Just implement a copy constructor and print a message in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be called, or it might not be called.  The compiler has the option of using the Return Value Optimization in both cases (though the optimization is a bit easier in `bar` than in `foo`).

Even if RVO eliminates the actual calls to the copy constructor, the copy constructor must still be defined and accessible.

Comment: There is also the NRVO option, that might actually be easier in foo. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Depends on the [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) being applied or not.

Answer (score 2):

It *may* be called.  It also may be optimized away.  See some [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665825/copy-constructor-vs-return-value-optimization) in the same direction.