# c++ copy constructor and operator= not invoked

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was doing some tests on copy constructors and operator=, but I got some weird results.

Here are my two test files test.h and test.cpp:

test.h

```
class CopyC {
public:
    CopyC() {
        cout << ">> In Default Constructor" << endl;
    }
    CopyC(const CopyC &other) {
        cout << ">> In Copy Constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~CopyC() {
        cout << ">> In Deconstructor" << endl;
    }

    CopyC& operator=(const CopyC &other) {
        cout << ">> In Operator =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    CopyC getCopy() {
        cout << ">> In getCopy" << endl;
        cout << "return CopyC()" << endl;
        return CopyC();
    }
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    cout << "CopyC c1" << endl;
    CopyC c1;
    cout << "CopyC c2 = c1.getCopy()" << endl;
    CopyC c2 = c1.getCopy();

    cout << "<< Finish" << endl;
}
```

I was using gcc 4.6.3 on linux amd64 with the command `g++ -o test -g3 test.cpp`. The output of `./test` is

```
CopyC c1
>> In Default Constructor
CopyC c2 = c1.getCopy()
>> In getCopy
return CopyC()
>> In Default Constructor
<< Finish
>> In Deconstructor
>> In Deconstructor
```

It seems that neither the copy constructor nor the operator= are invoked in the getCopy function. Did I missed something or I misunderstood something? Please help. Thanks in advance.

**update**:
Thanks to @Mike Seymour, now I know that this is a problem of copy elision. When I disabled g++ copy elision with `g++ -o test test.cpp -fno-elide-constructors`, the output looks more resonable:

```
CopyC c1
>> In Default Constructor
CopyC c2 = c1.getCopy()
>> In getCopy
return CopyC()
>> In Default Constructor
>> In Copy Constructor
>> In Deconstructor
>> In Copy Constructor
>> In Deconstructor
<< Finish
>> In Deconstructor
>> In Deconstructor
```

Comment: Do none of the related questions on the right answer your question? That would surprise me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

CopyC() in  getCopy() function will call the default constructor

`CopyC c2 = c1` will invoke copy constructor

refer to [Copy constructor vs. return value optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665825/copy-constructor-vs-return-value-optimization/665854#665854)

The standard says that the copy constructor need not be used - see section 12.8/15:

15 Whenever a temporary class object is copied using a copy constructor, and this object and the copy have the same cv-unqualified type, an implementation is permitted to treat the original and the copy as two different ways of referring to the same object and not perform a copy at all, even if the class copy constructor or destructor have side effects.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the copy constructor **isn't** invoked for `CopyC c2 = c1.getCopy();`. Luckily, there are plenty of duplicate questions explaining copy elision.

Answer (score 0):

In getCopy() function, you're calling CopyC() which is default constructor. For copy constructor function that you've written, you should call `CopyC(c1)` in getCopy() function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error might be in the the `getCopy()` function.

```
CopyC getCopy() {
    cout << ">> In getCopy" << endl;
    cout << "return CopyC()" << endl;
    return CopyC();
}
```

getCopy expects an object of class `CopyC` to be returned but instead the function `CopyC()` is returned which doesn't return anything itself.
A solution would be to create a CopyC object and return that.

```
CopyC getCopy() {
    cout << ">> In getCopy" << endl;
    cout << "return CopyC()" << endl;
    CopyC copy;
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: `CopyC` is a type, so `CopyC()`, when used as an expression, is a temporary instance.

Comment: oh ok thanks for clearing that up for me because i wasn't really positive about it

Answer (score 0):

some complier provide an optimization called "Name Return Value" .

```
CopyC getCopy() {
cout << ">> In getCopy" << endl;
cout << "return CopyC()" << endl;
return CopyC();
```

}

The code perhaps looks like this in complier :

```
void getCopy(CopyC &__result){
.....
__result.CopyC::CopyC();
```

}

so, neither the copy constructor nor the operator= are invoked in the getCopy function. 
I hope it helps.