# overloaded functions skipped on references

Tags: c++, reference, decorator, virtual-functions

The below code attempts to implement basic Decorator Design Pattern using references to refer to the base component class `Paragraph`

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::string;

// component
class Paragraph{
public:
   Paragraph(const string& text = "") : text_(text) {}
   virtual string getHTML() const { return text_; }
private:
   const string text_;
};

// first decorator
class BoldParagraph : public Paragraph {
public:
   BoldParagraph(const Paragraph& wrapped): wrapped_(wrapped) {}
   string getHTML() const override {
      return "<b>" + wrapped_.getHTML() + "</b>";
   }
private:
   const Paragraph &wrapped_;
};


// second decorator
class ItalicParagraph : public Paragraph {
public:
   ItalicParagraph(const Paragraph& wrapped): wrapped_(wrapped) {}
   string getHTML() const override {
      return "<i>" + wrapped_.getHTML() + "</i>";
   }
private:
   const Paragraph &wrapped_;
};

int main(){
   Paragraph p("Hello, World!");

   BoldParagraph     bp(p); cout <<  bp.getHTML() << endl;
   BoldParagraph   bbp(bp); cout << bbp.getHTML() << endl; 
   ItalicParagraph ibp(bp); cout << ibp.getHTML() << endl;
}
```

When run, it produces

```
<b>Hello, World!</b>
<b>Hello, World!</b>
<i><b>Hello, World!</b></i>
```

rather than

```
<b>Hello, World!</b>
<b><b>Hello, World!</b></b>
<i><b>Hello, World!</b></i>
```

That is, the second wrapped function `getHML()` appears to be skipped if it is for the same subclass `BoldParagraph` for object `bbp`, but not if it is for different subclasses `ItalicParagraph` and `BoldParagraph` for object `ibp`. Similar code with pointers rather than references works as expected.

why is that?

Comment: This is bizarre.  Happens in gcc and VS.  The `_wrapped` in `ibp` is the only one with a `BoldParagraph` vtable.

Comment: `&bbp.wrapped_` and `&p` are the same memory address.  Providing a copy constructor fixes it, but I'm honestly not sure how the default copy constructor could cause this to occur.

Comment: Oh... never mind.

Answer (score 1):

The default copy constructor is being called.  This creates a copy of your original object passed in (bp), rather than a wrapper around bp.  You *could* fix by declaring your own copy constructor, but I don't recommend it:

```
  BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph &wrapped) : wrapped_(wrapped) {}
```

To clarify, the default copy constructor copies the values passed in object, like so:

```
BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph &original) : wrapped_(original.wrapped_) {}
```

And, the more I think about it, the more I think my suggested fix is incorrect.  There can/probably will be nasty side-effects.  I would recommend fixing by making your constructors take pointers.

Answers here will show possible side-effects of having a copy constructor that does not perform a copy:
[Copy Constructor in C++ is called when object is returned from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665781/copy-constructor-in-c-is-called-when-object-is-returned-from-a-function)

A concrete example using a copy constructor that wraps instead of copies:

```
void AFunction(BoldParagraph bp)
{
  cout << bp.getHTML() << endl;
}
int main() {
  Paragraph p("Hello, World!");

  BoldParagraph     bp(p); cout << bp.getHTML() << endl;
  BoldParagraph   bbp(bp); cout << bbp.getHTML() << endl;
  AFunction(bbp);
```

output:

```
<b>Hello, World!</b>
<b><b>Hello, World!</b></b>
<b><b><b>Hello, World!</b></b></b>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `bbp(bp)` with `bp` being of type `BoldParagraph` calls the (implicitly defined) copy constructor `BoldParagraph::BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph &)`This then performs a member wise copy/assignment, such that `wrapper_` gets sliced and will then be of type `Paragraph &` rather than `BoldParagraph &`. To overcome this, you'll have to provide an explicit copy constructor for `BoldParagraph::BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph &)`, which then calls your individual one:

```
 BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph& wrapped) : BoldParagraph((Paragraph&)wrapped) {} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, great, thank you much! That was hard to spot. I ended up adding this

```
 BoldParagraph(const BoldParagraph& wrapped) : 
         BoldParagraph(static_cast<const Paragraph&>(wrapped)) {}
```

to make the code happy

Comment: Here's why you might not want to do that:  `void AFunction(BoldParagraph bp){  cout << bp.getHTML() << endl;}` Try calling this with bbp

Comment: eeek, have not thought of that