# How is operator+ implemented for strings?

Tags: c++

can anyone show me more or less how is it implemented because if, for example i have

```
string str1 = "hello";
string str2 = " world";
string str3 = str1 + str2;
```

so because the code executes from right to left,
this is getting executes, but how?
`str1 + str2`
i mean what the returned value?
because it needs to maybe allocate memory for some object and then return it and then how the memory will get free.
and also is there a operator+ in the vector class?
**EDIT**
thanks to everyone, i was just looking for to understand how the returned object is getting return because i thought that if the object is created inside the function so it'll get destroy after the function finished, but its not, so i can return an object that got created inside a function.

Comment: I think you need to read some documentation to better understand C++.One is about operators: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators . The other one may be an old answer on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665781/copy-constructor-in-c-is-called-when-object-is-returned-from-a-function . Hope it helps.

Comment: @StefanoBuora ohh, i read and i found out when an object getting created in function, so when the function finished, even if the object get created inside the function, it can still get return and can still be accessible, am i right?

Comment: If you are inside a function and you declare a string (let's call it automatic - not a pointer) it will be undefined behaviour to return that string to the caller). Even though the string itself it's implemented as a pointer to a char array, the class takes care of the object and make sure that the string object will be destroyed at the function exit. If you want to return a string from a function do it by passing a reference to the string, or return a pointer dynamically alocated which _make sure to delete_ when you don't need it anymore in order to avoid _memory leaks_

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu exactly!, that what i dont understand, so the function operator+ of the class string, how the function returns an object and then where the memory getting free?

Comment: The compiler introduces the code for creating the temporary for `str1 + str2` and it manages as well its destruction after its limited life-time which may end "after the `;`" of the `str3` initialization. Strictly speaking, I would expect that `str3` is used directly in-place instead of a temporary due to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B):

```cpp
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Alloc >
    std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>
        operator+( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& lhs,
                   const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Alloc>& rhs );
```

You're basically calling the templated function which boils down to (greatly simplified):

```
string str3 = operator+(str1, str2);
```

The `operator+` is responsible for constructing a *new* string out of the two provided and then this gets assigned to `str3`.

---

And, based on your comments elsewhere in this question, you seem to be suffering under the misapprehension that things allocated within a function cannot be returned.

That's actually *not* the case for dynamically allocated things like the content of strings. While it's almost always fatal to return the address of a *local* object in a function, dynamically allocated memory outlives the function quite nicely.

Comment: is the function returning an new temporary object that got memory allocated?

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile: yes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

A c++ `std::string` is implemented as a `char` array. But you will not see this implementation as there is the string class which wraps it for making your life easier. Instead, `string` class gives you a nice interface to use (as `std::string::operator+` for concatenation).

Related to the question, when you add `str1 + str2` there is the `std::string::operator+` function called and a temporary string will be generated (on the right side of the `=` operator). The newly created object (let's call it `str_temp` and consider it looks like this `"hello world"` ) will be used by `str3` to create a new object (of course it will allocate memory dynamically but it will not allocate only 12 elements, but will alocate chunks of bytes). [for example a string with 3 chars can have a length of 3 chars but a size of 15 bytes].

In the example you provided, both `str1` and `str2` will remain unmodified.

On the following link [cppreference std::string::operator+ function signature](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/) you can see on what kind of parameters is `+` going to work when talking about strings. Therefore the next example works as expected, showing three times on the screen the message *hello world*.

```
std::string a = "hello ";
std::string b = "world";

std::string result1 = a + "world";
std::string result2 = "hello " + b;
std::string result3 = a + b;

std::cout << result1 << "\n" << result2 << "\n" << result3 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Worth noting that `str1` must be `std::string` and not `char*`, e.g. `string str3 = "hello" + str2;` fails.

Comment: ohhh thank you very much, but the new object will allocate memory so where does the memory getting free?

Comment: The destructor for the new std::string object.

Comment: Please, add `std::` in front of `string`.

Comment: but how the destructor know if the string  for example str3 got the memory allocated from the new temporary object that got created from str1 + str2, or the str3 didnt get memory allocated and just regular string

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin string also have implemented the concatenation with char* arrays http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/

Comment: But only if the FIRST is `std::string`, e.g. `std::string str3 = str1 + " world";` is fine.

Comment: Did you mean to refer to `operator+=`? I'm not sure that comes into play here.

Comment: @paxdiablo sory my mistake I was ctrl+f the operator+ and I did not watch carefully

Answer (score 3):

### [Operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

Forget `std::string`. Imagine you have a simple position class, which holds `x` and `y` coordinates in a 2 dimensional world

```cpp
struct Position {
    int x;
    int y;
    Position( const int x, const int y)
        : x(x), y(y)
    {}
};
int main()
{
    Position s( 5, 10 );
    Position t( 20, 30);
}
```

Now let's say the I wanted to **add** these positions, so that I get a new position where `x = 25 , y = 40`. Can I just use `+`?

```cpp
Position sum = s + t; // error
                 ^
              No match for operator '+', Operands are `Position`, `Position`
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How is the compiler supposed to know how to add `Position` and `Position`? As I said, [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

For this example it would be

```cpp
    friend Position operator+(const Position& r, const Position& l)
    {
        return Position(r.x + l.x, r.y + l.y);
    }
```

Now the error disappears, and the new object formed will have the correct values. 
The same way, `std::string` has overloaded `operator+`which takes two other `std::string`s objects and concatenates them.

Once it constructs the new string, it copies it into `str3`.

---

> I thought that if the object is created inside the function so it'll
> get destroy after the function finished, but its not, so i can return
> an object that got created inside a function.

Consider this example

```cpp
int foo()
{
    int temp = 10;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    int i = foo();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

> 10

You're not actually returning `temp` from the function. That variable is completely destroyed. What you are doing is returning a **copy**, which gets assigned to `i`.

What will fail is

```cpp
int& foo()
{
    int temp = 10;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    int& i = foo();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

<sup>Make sure to disable optimizations when you test this</sup> 

This fails because now you are returning a reference to an object that is destroyed.  Note that it isn't necessary this **has** to fail. Anything that happens after doing the above is undefined behavior.

The compiler is god so it just might translate your code into

```cpp
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

---

Because of all this, the compiler will decide to do something else because copying will be in-efficient if the object is huge, that is [return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: Always better to link to cpprefernce.com, e.g. [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) it is considered the best secondary reference if not citing the standard. But, a good example explaining the concept.

Comment: so is it possible to return this even it is out of the function memory?

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Operator overloading is a specific feature of the C++ language, and you can define the overloads needed for your circumstance, for any class. In the case of string concatenation, it is already provided by `std::string`, but this example explains the general way that overloading of operators get defined for any given class.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My bad, I wrote this answer quickly and didn't realize I cited TutorialsPoint, I fixed the link now

Comment: No worries, it was just offered as a helpful tip `:)`

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile I have just given an example of how `+` works between the strings. What's happening behind is a lot of memory management since the whole `std::string` class just works on a `char []`

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile You can read my answer now, I directly answered what you asked after the edit

Comment: @AryanParekh do you know maybe if its allowed to return value like that in C?
because i learned C and from what i remember its not allowed, this is also the reason i didnt understand

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile return like what?  Do you mean returning by `&` ?

Comment: ohhhh sorry now i get it, so the address of the variable is not the same as the address of the variable that is returned because it is just a copy, thank you!

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile Exactly :)